# what is the CIDR range for the AWS CodeBuild service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

In my codebuild project I want to connect to a private 3rd party service.

Which range of IPs should this service accept to allow CodeBuild to connect to it?

Comment: Any whitelist based upon an AWS service public IP range whitelist includes you and any other AWS customer using that service, so it's not a good solution. An Elastic IP would be an option in VPC/EC2, for example, because it's your EIP and won't be reassigned to a different customer (until you give it back). Could you incorporate EC2 in your CI/CD pipeline somehow?

Comment: You mean create an ec2 proxy instance? I would prefer to avoid that

Comment: You can't control the IPs of the CodeBuild servers so your alternative would be to use CodeBuild within your own VPC. That would allow you to handle outbound traffic and route it via a NAT with a static IP. You can then whitelist that IP. Or rely primarily on authenticated requests at the remote server.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html for jarmod's comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can find the CIDR ranges from [ip-ranges.json](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json).

In case you want to get the CIDR ranges using code, refer to [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html).

Comment: Is this list dynamic?

Comment: I guess it does. but better keep an eye of these things once in a while