# CIDR range AWS Service details

Tags: amazon-web-services, cidr

Does any one have an Idea to which service of Amazon does this CIDR range belong?
I saw that JSON t https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json 
 but I am not able to understand what does service:AMAZON mean. from the file I see below IP CIDR. how can I know this is used by which end point?

"ip_prefix": "52.94.76.0/22", 
"region": "us-west-2", 
"service": "AMAZON", 
"network_border_group": "us-west-2"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the CIDR range for the AWS CodeBuild service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921239/what-is-the-cidr-range-for-the-aws-codebuild-service)

Answer (score 1):

AWS publishes their full IP ranges in their [ip-ranges.json](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) document here.

These ranges actually appear to cover a large number of smaller ranges, so it is worth reviewing this.

Comment: I saw that JSON, but I am not able to understand what does service:AMAZON mean.
from the file I see below IP CIDR. how can I know this is used by which end point? 

      "ip_prefix": "52.94.76.0/22",
      "region": "us-west-2",
      "service": "AMAZON",
      "network_border_group": "us-west-2"

Comment: The `AMAZON` service just covers a larger range, the other services cover subsets of the `AMAZON` range. So you would see potentially multiple services in the `AMAZON` range, these will be covered in the json file too.

Comment: That is what is my understanding concern, when you say it covers a wider range, what service comes in this range or what could be the hostname?
because when I check other end point, it says, service is EC2, and hostname is EC2 instance.
I also see it say that service is Amazon, but host is S3, cloudflare, cloudfront etc. but in this it doesnt show anything

Comment: It appears that the IP range there is not being used yet, however as an example the `35.180.0.0/16` ranger for eu-west-3 also covers "EC2" and "EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT" in the region.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but for me used case is CIDR 52.94.76.0/22. and I have no clue abt it, I am able to figure out rest of service, but only issue is with IP CIDR that have service:AMAZON. as mention in my question  or in previous comment